# How to apply toggleClass to an element? Galleria

Tags: javascript, jquery, galleria

I try to build my custom theme, based on "Galleria theme Classic", but I'm straggling to trigger class on my button, I think, I miss something,

```
   this.addElement('play').appendChild('container','play');
   var g = this;
   this.$('play').text('Play').bind('mouseup', function() {
            g.playToggle();
            g.toggleClass("highlight"); // - This line don't work
});
```

I get error @TypeError: g.toggleClass is not a function@

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're calling toggleClass on the wrong element, or the element is not jQuery wrapped (not quite clear from posted code). Try this:

```
$(g).toggleClass('highlight');
```

Or this:

```
g.$('play').toggleClass('highlight');
```

Comment: thx so much, 

g.$('play').toggleClass('highlight'); - this work fine, 

oh ...., what a simple fail

Answer (score 2):

For reference, [`element.classList.toggle("classname")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.classList) is another option.